# 7 Linux distributions on 1 1.4TB external hard drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I know this may sound weird, but is there any way I can fit 7 Linux distributions on 1 1.4TB hard drive (plus 8.5GB swap)?

If so, would I have to make one extended partition, and put the rest of the partitions as logical, since only 4 primary partitions are allowed, or how would I do it?

Comment: GPT does not have the 4 primary partitions limit.

Comment: Why not use Virtual Machines?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad... the answer could be yes or no, or something different but there is not enough information to make a definitive answer.

Comment: a basic linux installation can fit in ~5-10GB or so, even with a relatively full desktop environment.  give each distro a root partition of ~25GB and you still have 1.2TB of free space to play with.  (GPT + EFI strongly recommended.)

Comment: 8.5GB swap? I hope that the drive has a fast connection, like ESATA, Thunderbolt or firewire. USB(2) might be darn slow.

Comment: why not? you can install [145 Linux distros or any other number of OSes on a "tiny" PC](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?147959-How-to-install-and-boot-145-operating-systems-in-a-PC). A 8GB USB stick can easily fit 4-6 distros at once. You don't need big swap either

Comment: Your right, I have 8GB ram, 1.4TB USB 3.0 external Hard drive (Seagate), how much swap should I have

Comment: RE: Swap size that is PURELY your call as it will depend on your use-cases for each and whether you are using a shared swap that ALL distros access or have their own sovereign swap partitions.  Something that will have VMs should have decent swap, something that is a simply  webserver for say a school project webserver not so much, also is hybernation or suspend planed for any of these installs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Since I can't reply to the comments to close the question as "too broad", I'll say here that the question is not too broad, and the answer is a discrete "yes".  It is not yes/no/maybe.  Furthermore, asking how to create an externally bootable device with partitioning is relevant to the superuser channel.

Yes to both your questions.  Create 3 primary, 1 extended.  Put 5 partitions in the extended volume, one of them (in the extended) will be swap.

After that, there's 2 ways:

1. **The less easy**

   The tricky part is that you'll need to treat one of your first 3 primary linux partitions as a kind of "master".  {1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,swap}} You'll install linux into it and then edit the grub.conf file to list all the kernels and partitions in the extended partition.  You'll also have to be careful other linux installs don't clobber the "master" bootloader. Remember to make the first bootable.
2. **"easier"**

   (probably more reliable, but a chance for collision).  Create 9 partitions.  Make the first partition a larger than normal boot partition. {boot,1,2,{3,4,5,6,7,swap}} Into that partition you'll put all the kernels and initrd files for all the other partitions, including those linuxes in the extended partition.  You'll have to be careful that each later install doesn't format the boot partition.  Remember to make the first bootable.
3. **best**

   The easiest (and best, I think) solution (that I use) is to get 7 32/64GB usb sticks.  Stick in a usb stick, and when installing linux, instead of selecting the hard drive to partition and install to, select the usb stick.  Only create a swap partition on the hard drive.  Then label all your usb sticks with their different linuxes and pop each in when you want to run it.  Way easier and more portable than partitioning up the HD and managing a bunch of different bootloader settings. HD {swap,data|home}.  Put swap first in this scenario to allow yourself the ability to resize the data partition.

**Notes:** While the answer is generally yes to all of your questions, the fact that its an external usb drive is going to present you with some (non)trivialities.  Number 1, if the computer is not set to boot from usb, it may not work.  If the computer doesn't "keep" the "boot from usb" setting (say as the #1 boot priority), it'll quickly become tedious or go to hell when you make a mistake.  I can tell you want all your linuxes in one external-place, with some shared data, but you'll also have to be aware of the drive letter remapping that may take place after the kernel takes over and puts the internal drive on sda.  e.g. ALL the partitions will have to be referenced by UUID.

Um, maybe add 1 more partition in extended there to be your shared home, across all the linux distros.

Don't use GPT.  You'll be sorry if you have to boot an older computer.

Comment: `Don't use GPT. You'll be sorry if you have to boot an older computer.` how do you know if he's using a new or old computer?

Comment: I don't.  OP is installing on an external hard drive, so it could be used on either a newer computer or an older one.

Comment: Your point `3.` is an answer to "How do I put 7 Linux distributions on 7 USB sticks?".

Comment: @simlev.  No, "Use GPT" is **not the answer**.  OP did not specify if he/she has UEFI supporting BIOS, and GPT is only supported in later BIOS versions. By the time a person is asking to install *7* linux distributions, they want to explore both the differences in the distributions themselves, AND in the distributions' support for hardware.  Linux was originally designed to support older hardware, such as non-UEFI, non GPT supporting BIOS.

Comment: you can put an ESP (EFI System Partition ie the EFI boot partition) on an MBR-partitioned drive and many UEFI systems will happily recognize and boot from it.  format it as FAT32 with an `EFI` folder in the root.  install `grub` to both the MBR and the EFI partition and it will work on most systems.

Comment: @quixotic, true